# Is there a data structure for implementing a function equivalent to 'tail -n' command in C++?

Tags: c++, filesystems, tail

I want to write a function equivalent to the Linux tail -n command in C++. While, I parsed over the data of that file line-by-line thereby incrementing the line count, if the file size gets really big(~gigabytes), this method will take a lot of time! Is there a better approach or a data structure to implement this function?

Here are my 2 methods:

```
int File::countlines()
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    string str;

    if (file)
       {
            while (getline(file, str))
            {
                lineCount += 1;
            }
     }
   return lineCount;
}

void File::printlines()
{
    int lineCount = 0;
    string line;

    if (file)
    {
        lineCount = countlines();

        file.clear();
        file.seekg(ios::beg);

        if (lineCount <= 10)
        {
             while (getline(file, line))
             {
                 cout << line << endl;
             }
        }
        else
        {
            int position = lineCount - 10;
            while (position--)
            {
                getline(file, line);
            }
           while (getline(file, line))
           {
               cout << line << endl;
           }
       }
}
}
```

This method is time consuming if the file size increases, so I want to either replace it with another data structure, or write a more efficient code.

Comment: `std::getline` constructs a `std::string`, you don't need that when you just count eol.

Comment: [`std::basic_istream::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) might help.

Comment: if `lineCount` is parametrable, then `std::endl` is also "problematic" with extra flush.

Comment: You could read a block of a certain size from end of file, then look whether you find the n + 1 lines at end. If not read a second block before this etc. Sounds like a lot of fiddling but to save the time of reading gigabytes of data just to skip all but the last n lines it could be worth the effort. FYI: [std::istream::seekg()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg), [std::istream::tellg()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)

Comment: The suggestion by @Scheff'sCat is what [tail](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the things that is slowing down your program is reading the file twice, so you could keep the last n EOL positions (n=10 in your program) and the most convenient data structure is a circular buffer but this isn't provided by the standard library as far as I know (boost has one). It can be implemented by an std::vector with size n, with an index where a modulo of n is done after incrementing.

With that circular buffer, you can jump immediately to the lowest offset (next one if buffer is full) in the file and print the needed lines.

Answer (score 1):

When I've done this, I've done a generous estimate of the maximum length of a line (e.g., one kilobyte), `seek`ed to that distance from the end, and started reading lines into a circular buffer until the end of the file.

In *nearly* every case, you get more than `n` lines, so you just print out the contents of the circular buffer, and you're done. Note, however, that you do need to assure that you read *more* than `n` lines, not just `n` lines. The first line you read will usually only be a partial line, so if you read exactly `n` lines, the first would probably be only a partial line.

On rare occasion, you haven't gotten the required number of lines, so you seek back twice as far (or other factor of your choice), and restart. If you want to get really fancy, you can extrapolate the number of lines you'll need based on the average length of the lines you did read (but honestly, this is such a rare situation it's not worth a lot of work to optimize it).

This normally works essentially instantly, regardless of file size. I suppose (in theory) for a file with incredibly long lines, it would get slower, but if that's the case, the user has probably made a mistake, and tried to tail something that isn't a text file (which is generally useless anyway).

Comment: The idea of using a circular buffer did click me, I just wasn't sure about handling its edge case. Thank you so much for summarizing that bit!